# how to use includes? with belongs_to relationship, ERROR = undefined method `includes?' for

Tags: include, ruby-on-rails-4, belongs-to

my user model is as shown below `user.rb`

```
has_many :authorised_downloads, 
:class_name=>"Downloads",
:primary_key => 'id', 
:foreign_key=> :authorised_user_id
```

downloads model `download.rb`

```
belongs_to :authorised_users, 
:class_name => "User",
:primary_key => 'id',
:foreign_key=> :authorised_user_id
```

downloads controller

```
def download
@download = Download.find(params[:id])
if @download.authorised_users.includes?(current_user)
  send_file(@download.upload_file.path,
  :filename => @download.name,       
  :x_sendfile=>true,
  :url_based_filename => true )               
  flash[:notice] = "Your file has been downloaded"
else
   flash[:notice] = "You must buy the product first!"
end
end
```

in my downloads view, when i click the download link, the line `if @download.authorised_users.includes?(current_user)` in the download controller is highlighted with the following error

```
undefined method `includes?' for #<User:0x00000005c2ff10>
```

I dont understand where i when wrong. Your assistance will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@download.authorised_users` return an instance of User, not collection. B/c `belongs_to :authorised_users`

Try:

```
belongs_to :authorised_user, :class_name => "User"
```

And in controller:

```
if @download.authorised_user == current_user
```